# What type of connector is this (16-pin, 1-row)?

Tags: identification, connector

I came across a (dead) board and am trying to figure out how it might be revived. The board has this connector, which seems to be connected to a
ADSP-BF533 processor. From BF533's specification I believe that it might be an (unusual) representation of a JTAG port. To figure out a possible pin assignment it would be nice to know the type of connector, maybe it has been used as a JTAG port somewhere else?
Unfortunately, even after hours of looking through connector catalogs I have not been able to figure out what kind of plug this might be. It is 19mm wide and has 16 pins pitched by 1mm.
[image: Unknown Plug]

Comment: How important is it that the PCB be revived?

Comment: what does the plug have to do with reviving the board? ... what device contains that board?

Comment: I have edited the post to clarify the (possible) role of the connector in my quest to revive the board. As for the importance of reviving the board - it's for a hobby project.